# Is there something like Java Quartz in ruby?

Tags: java, ruby, quartz-scheduler

The is a library like Quartz in Java for ruby?

Comment: c0mrade... i know cron.. but if i am asking i need a job scheduling and queuing framework not only a simple cron  (to be explict i really don't need cron functionality)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There nothing quite as fully featured as Quartz for Ruby. There is the [whenever gem](http://github.com/javan/whenever) which you could integrate with one of the many [job queuing frameworks](http://ruby-toolbox.com/categories/queueing.html). Or, if you are are prepared to consider using JRuby, then you can fully integrate with Quartz directly.

Answer (score 2):

**Cron replacements that use a long running ruby process:**

Check out the [Clockwork](https://github.com/tomykaira/clockwork) ruby gem.  This gives a very simple DSL and runner.

If you need something more advanced, check out the [Rufus-Scheduler](https://github.com/jmettraux/rufus-scheduler) gem.  It looks like you will have to do some legwork to use this in a long running process, however it is much more powerful than clockwork and supports EventMachine.

Comment: Rufus-Scheduler seems pretty awesome.
I am searching for a way to schedule and re-schedule jobs at runtime.

With Wheneverize I was only capable of setting buch of scheduled jobs at the moment of starting up my server. That was insufficient for me.

Haven't yet tried Rufus-Scheduler but I will try to report later how it works.